# ios Home Screen Widget Not working Build using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, socket.io, home-screen-widget

I have created a ios app using flutter which needs a homescreen widget for showing live rate of gold and silver which is Intgerated from socket.So I created a Homescreen widget for my app using swift,but the problem is thaht the widget is showing the Expected Result.Please Help me to resolve this.Below is my Code

```
//
//  liveratewidget.swift
//  liveratewidget
//
//  Created by Artifitia on 11/07/23.
//
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import Intents
import SocketIO
var bidPrice: String = "Loading..."
struct Provider: IntentTimelineProvider {
    let socketManager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "https://testsocket.bullionview.com/")!, config: [.log(false),.forceWebsockets(true), .compress])
//    var bidPrice: String = "Loading..."
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        SimpleEntry(date: Date(), configuration: ConfigurationIntent(), bidPrice: bidPrice)
    }
    func getSnapshot(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
        let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date(), configuration: configuration, bidPrice: bidPrice)
        completion(entry)
    }
    func getTimeline(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        var _: [SimpleEntry] = []
    let currentDate = Date()
    // Connect to the socket and listen for "gold-rate-change" event
    let socket = socketManager.defaultSocket
        socket.on("gold-rate-change") {data, ack in
         //   guard let self = self else { return }
                   if let dataArray = data as? [[String: Any]],
                      let bidPriceData = dataArray[0]["data"] as? [String: Any],
                      let bid = bidPriceData["bid"] as? Double {
                       bidPrice = String(bid)
                   }
            print(bidPrice)
            guard let cur = data[0] as? Double else { return }
        }
//    socket.on("gold-rate-change") { [weak self] (data, _) in
//        guard let self = self else { return }
//        if let dataArray = data as? [[String: Any]],
//           let bidPriceData = dataArray[0]["data"] as? [String: Any],
//           let bid = bidPriceData["bid"] as? Double {
//            self.bidPrice = String(bid)
//        }
//        let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: entries.count, to: currentDate)!
//        let entry = SimpleEntry(date: entryDate, configuration: configuration, bidPrice: self.bidPrice)
//        entries.append(entry)
//        if entries.count >= 5 {
//            socket.disconnect()
//            let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
//            completion(timeline)
//        }
   // }
    socket.connect()
}
}
struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
    let configuration: ConfigurationIntent
    let bidPrice: String
}
struct liveratewidgetEntryView: View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Gold Price" )
                .font(.title)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
            Text(bidPrice)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
struct liveratewidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "liveratewidget"
    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        IntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: ConfigurationIntent.self, provider: Provider()) { entry in
            liveratewidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("Gold Bid Rate")
        .description("Displays the current bid price for Gold.")
        .supportedFamilies([.systemSmall, .systemMedium, .systemLarge])
    }
}
struct liveratewidget_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        liveratewidgetEntryView(entry: SimpleEntry(date: Date(), configuration: ConfigurationIntent(), bidPrice: bidPrice))
            .previewContext(WidgetPreviewContext(family: .systemSmall))
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxZdM.png)
this is result